# From a url string, how can i get the file path without file name and param

Tags: javascript

var url = 'http ://domain.com/file.php?id=1';
or

var url = 'https ://domain.com/file.php?id=1';
or

var url = 'https ://domain.com';
or

from either one of these urls I want to get only the path, like the one below:

var path = 'https ://domain.com';

and lastly if the url is

var url = 'https ://domain.com/sg';

i should get

var path = 'https ://domain.com/sg';

Comment: Completepath.replace(location.search,"");

Comment: hi, thanks for ur reply. but that will only remove the param.

Comment: your question is not clear 
and lastly if the url is

var url = 'https ://domain.com/sg';

i should get

var path = 'https ://domain.com/sg';

both are same

Comment: You can do this with string operations or use `new URL("http://domain.com/file.php?id=1");`

Comment: if the url is https ://domain.com/sg i should get the path as https ://domain.com/sg which is correct. /sg is a folder not a file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this working example. It should work in your case.

https://jsfiddle.net/ch44Lmuk/10/

```
function getnewUrl(url) {
    url = url.replace("http://", "");
    var index = url.indexOf('/');
    if (index == -1) return url;
    else {
        var split = url.split('/')
        var domain = split[0];
        if (split[1].length == 0) return domain;
        url = url.slice(index);
        index = url.lastIndexOf('.');

        if (index != -1) {
            index = url.lastIndexOf('/');
            url = url.slice(0, index);
        } else {
            index = url.lastIndexOf('/');
            if (index == url.length - 1) url = url.slice(0, index);
        }
        return domain + url;
    }
}
```

Comment: perfect answer.. what a player